# GraphQL nuGet v4 DateTimeGraphType

Tags: c#, graphql, nuget

I have an existing GraphQL endpoint written in C# using the GraphQL NuGet package (v3.3.2) that returns new contact details based on a supplied date time value:

```
{
    contactsCreated(fromDate:"2021-03-01")
}
```

When I upgrade the NuGet package to the latest version (v4.0.2) the same query returns an error relating to the date parameter:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Argument 'fromDate' has invalid value. Expected type 'DateTime', found \"2021-03-01\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 19
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "ARGUMENTS_OF_CORRECT_TYPE",
        "codes": [
          "ARGUMENTS_OF_CORRECT_TYPE"
        ],
        "number": "5.6.1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The query will now only complete successfully, if I pass a full ISO8601 date time string (e.g. 2021-03-01T00:00:00).  Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour; has the parsing of query parameters become more strict in version 4?

Comment: Looking at the docs, it does seem to require an ISO8601 datetime string. Perhaps try using `DateGraphType` instead?

Comment: The query needs to accept a date time parameter value; during normal operation the caller wouldn't be supplying just a date.  But most languages / frameworks I have come across will allow you to set a date time variable using just a date string, this normally (although not always) results in the time portion being defaulted to 00:00:00.